# In my React-Native, app, I am looking to see if the use is logged in before I initialize the beginning scene

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-native, render, scene

Here is my most recent attempt of trying to render the scene. I was originally attempting to do it in the `renderScene` function, but tried another method.  The problem here is that `_loadInitialState()` doesn't finish running before the initial scene runs.  I'm sure there is a better way to do this anyways.  Here my component:

```
get initialScene;

class MainNav extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this._loadInitialState().done();
  }

  async _loadInitialState() {
    try {
      let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("tokenKey");
      if (token !== null) {
         initialScene = 'home';
      } else {
         initialScene = 'login';
        console.log(token);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
   }
 }

  renderScene(route, nav) {

    switch(route.name) {
      case 'login':
      return (
        <Login />
      );

      case 'home':
      return (
    <MainCamera />
  )
}
}

  render() {
    return(
      <Navigator
        _loadInitialState={this._loadInitialState.bind(this)}
        initialRoute={{name: initialScene}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your running your code in `componentDidMount` so your app waits till the UI is rendered. Why don't you just do it in your constructor like:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this._loadInitialState().done();
}
```

Or you can just simply do it in another class as a dispatcher that checks whether the user is logged in or not and then it does the navigation and the dispatcher doesn't have any interface or it just could be a splash page depending on your use case.

Comment: When I originally did this, I was getting the error of `this._loadInitialState() is not a function`, so I decided to move all of that code inside of the constructor.  This kind of worked, but each time I received an object that looked like this: `Promise {_45: 0, _81: 0, _65: null, _54: null}`.  Notice that all of these values are null, but when I expand the screen, the token in stringified JSON form appears after the `_65` value.  So I tried to check if token._65 was null instead, but because the collapsed view of the object says the value is null, then null is returned no matter what.